# How to compare same column in the same table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table with following records

```
Name             Seq                  Join                     Resign
---------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------------
Joe              1                    2001-11-04 00:00:00.000  2005-03-31 00:00:00.000
Joe              2                    2005-04-01 00:00:00.000  NULL
Jane             1                    2011-12-04 00:00:00.000  2013-02-01 00:00:00.000
Jane             2                    2015-05-01 00:00:00.000  NULL
Jack             1                    2001-01-01 00:00:00.000  2002-01-01 00:00:00.000
Jack             2                    2002-01-02 00:00:00.000  2003-01-01 00:00:00.000
Jack             3                    2005-01-01 00:00:00.000  2006-01-01 00:00:00.000
Jack             4                    2006-01-02 00:00:00.000  NULL
```

So I'm trying to find out Employee `Join Date`, `Seq` represents hire number, so if an Employee resign and later rejoin the company, the `Seq` will increase. But the problem is `Seq` will also increase when Employee get a promotion or move to another department.

In my case, Joe has 2 `Seq` but he never resigned because his 2nd Join Date = Resign Date + 1. So my final expected result is

- Joe, 2001-11-04
- Jane, 2015-05-01
- Jack, 2005-01-01 (because he resigned after 2nd hire)

Any idea how to get this result without looping?

Note: `Seq` can be 1,2,3,4 and so on depends on how many promotion or resign/rejoin on each employee

Jack expected result is `2005-01-01` because from 1st hire to 2nd is not an actual resignation because 2nd hire JoinDate = 1st hire ResignDate + 1 `2002-01-01 = 2002-01-02 + 1`. But from 2nd hire to 3rd hire is an actually resignation because `2003-01-01 != 2005-01-01 + 1`. I hope that make sense.

Comment: To make things clearer, add some more sample data (tricky data),.

Comment: I think you mispelled some data (2001-11 instead of 2010?)

Comment: Do you want just the max (SEQ or DATA) or do you want to exclude only the records not resigned?

Comment: @warheat1990, for `Jack`, he resigned after the 3rd hire, didn't he?

Comment: I think OP is using the difference between resignation and next join dates as the indication of whether it's an actual resignation or a promotion: 1 day = promotion, more days = actual resignation

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi: For Jack, the expected result is `2005-01-01` because from 1st hire to 2nd is not an actual resignation because 2nd hire JoinDate = 1st hire ResignDate + 1 `2002-01-01 = 2002-01-02`. But from 2nd hire to 3rd hire is an actually resignation because `2003-01-01 != 2005-01-01 + 1`. I hope that make sense.

Comment: @warheat1990, let's say jack signs of and reasigns again later, which date you want to have? Only the last new hire date or both?

Comment: @Kevin: Only the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
SELECT B.NAME, JJOIN  
FROM (SELECT *
    , LAG(DD1) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY RMAX) AS DD1_PREC
   FROM  
    (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY SEQ DESC) AS RMAX 
        , LEAD(RESIGN) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY SEQ DESC) AS PREC_RESIGN
        ,  DATEDIFF(dd,LEAD(RESIGN) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY SEQ DESC),JJOIN) AS DD1
    FROM TABLEX) A
    ) B
WHERE (RMAX =1 AND DD1>1 ) 
     OR (RMAX = 2 AND DD1_PREC<=1)
```

Output:

```
NAME                 JJOIN
-------------------- -----------------------
Jack                 2005-01-01 00:00:00.000
Jane                 2015-05-01 00:00:00.000
Joe                  2010-11-04 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: This gives wrong date if you skip resignation for `Jack` and set first date as actual joining date

Answer (score 0):

This is more easy to understand

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  res.*, 
       --df = 0 if join and resign dates have difference greater than 1 else df = 1
                DATEDIFF(Day, IsNull(jn.Resign, res.JoinDate), res.JoinDate) df,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY res.Name ORDER BY res.Name DESC) AS rn
    FROM    [dbo].[tblWarheat1990] res
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tblWarheat1990] jn ON res.JoinDate = DATEADD(day, 1, jn.Resign)
    )
    , gte as (
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by name ORDER BY rn DESC) AS minimum 
    FROM    cte 
    WHERE   df = 0)

    SELECT * FROM gte WHERE minimum = 1
    ORDER BY rn DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You want the maximum `join` date where there is no `resign` date one day before.

I would do this as:

```
select t.name, max(t.join)
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.join = dateadd(day, 1, tprev.resign)
where t.prev.resign is null
group by name;
```

Alternatively, you can do this using `seq` and `lag()`:

```
select name, max(join)
from (select t.*,
             lag(t.resign) over (partition by t.name order by t.seq) as prev_resign
      from t
     ) t
where prev_resign is null or prev_resign <> dateadd(day, -1, resign)
group by name;
```